# Network port listening

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am writing an application (an instant messenger). I would like to know whether IOS supports application to listen to a particular ports for incoming packet continuously (when the application is active not suspend).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**

Long answer: [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321028/network-port-listening/4321043#4321043) provided a link how to deal with sockets using *CFNetwork Framework*.
I'd like to add the hint for [*cocoa-asyncsocket*](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/), a light-weight object-orientated wrapper for that framework. A true time-saver.

Answer (score 1):

Survey says: yes.

http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html